# Apache CXF Out Interceptor change fault Response

Tags: cxf, interceptor

How would I be able to handle a soap fault in cxf out interceptor but changing the response from fault to success response, I am also using ws-addressing and WSS4J as part of the response.

I am struggling to return a

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
       ws-address- ws-security
<soap:Body>
          <Response>
            Ok!
          </Response>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

rather I am currently getting

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Fault occurred while processing.</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) says:
*Additionally, in the case of SOAPFaults, a CXF web service will create a separate outbound error handling chain and the client will create an inbound error handling chain.*

So I think you have to add a InFaultInterceptor/OutFaultInterceptor where you can handle your response message.

Comment: I have added the OutFaultInterceptor that's where I catch the error but I want to remove the soap fault and insert a success response, question is how do i change the message response without losing the ws-addressiing and ws-security header!

Comment: Ok, I think then you are right with the transformation feature where you can modify the soap response: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html